# In which file eclipse "deployment assembly" configurations are at?

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't seem to find this configuration at .project file. I am looking for a way to change this setting programmatically as "I don't know why" my eclipse is losing this configuration every time I clean the project.

Comment: Have you searched in workspace properties? [path to workspace]\.metadata

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The deployment assembly settings are stored in the file:

```
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
```

However, in a basic J2EE Eclipse install this file shouldn't be modified by cleaning the project. Maybe you have some other plugin installed that is updating the deployment settings during the build.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and the reason being that the  file **.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component** contained entries added by Git. On removing them, and restarting the eclipse worked for me.