# Eclipse deployment assemble cannot find entry for project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I  converted X  normal java project to maven project. Earier this X project was used in the deployment assemble of Y project, now when I am the X project into the deployment assembly of Y project , I am getting can not find entry for X project.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to add it as "Project" but add it as "Archives from Workspace":

1. Remove project "IBEJB" from Deployment Assembly.
2. Click "Add".
3. Choose "Archives from Workspace".
4. Click "Add".
5. Choose IBEJB/target/IBEJB-*.jar.
6. Click "Finish".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the dependent project into *faceted form*, in Project properties => Project Facets.